# string_replace &raquo

Tags: php, xml

I have the following as XML output for `$result->label` in PHP:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[0] =>  Page Title » Site Title
)
```

Now I need to replace the ' » Site Title' with nothing ('') but I cannot get it to work:

```
$result_title = str_replace(' » Site Title','',$result_title); // Doesn't work
$result_title = str_replace(' &raquo Site Title','',$result_title); // Doesn't work
$result_title = str_replace(' &#187; Site Title','',$result_title); // Doesn't work
$result_title = str_replace(' Site Title','',$result_title); // Works
```

The last one works so I know that it is just the '&raquo' that is causing trouble.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**: Running var_dump(preg_split('//u', $result_title)) outputs:

```
[10]=> string(2) "»"
```

Comment: Would `preg_replace('#(?<=Page Title)(.+)$#', '', $result->label)` be enough for you? )

Comment: `&#187;` and `&raquo;` are HTML entities and do not work in PHP.

Comment: Anyway, `preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z]+Site Title#', '', $result_title);` should surely be enough. )

Comment: @raina77ow Thank you. Damn, I've been avoiding preg matches but I guess they are a necessity for today's programmer. Don't you say? Put this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Ok, glad to help. ) But one more thing to be sure: can you give the result of `var_dump(preg_split('//u', $result_title));` here?

Comment: Not sure why you need that output. One annoying tidbit is that there is a white space before the string starts so I need another preg_replace. I tried using trim but it did not output every result for some reason

Comment: I actually wondered how exactly this symbol - `»` - is represented in that string. Still, it shouldn't matter much, I suppose.

Comment: Ah, see my edit. Also, I had to break off my previous comment into a new Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521634/xml-parsing-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to erase the `Site Title` substring along with all the non-character symbols preceding it is to use `preg_replace` function:

```
$result_title = 'Page Title » Site Title';
$result_title = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z]+Site Title#', '', $result_title);
```