# XML parsing: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'suggest'

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
$results = simplexml_load_string($results);
foreach($results as $result){
    $result_title = $result->label;
    $result_title = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z]+Extra Title#', '', $result_title);
    $result_title = ltrim($result_title);
```

The first preg_replace gets rid of a pattern at the end of the $result->label (which var_dumps as an XML object) and outputs, not an XML object, but a string.

This is surprising because I thought that preg_replace would only work on **strings** and not the XML object. A `var_dump` of the $result reveals:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1003 (1) { [0]=> string(31) " Some Text > Extra Title" }
```

Note the extra white space before 'Some Text'. The second `ltrim($result_title);`, however, causes this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'suggest'

So what am I dealing with? A string or an object? And how do I trim the whitespace?

Trying a preg_replace for the first whitespace also outputs the same error as above.

```
$result_title = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $result_title, 1);
```

Comment: "Has no method `suggest`" doesn't sound like it has to do with `ltrim`.  Are you sure it's not something else?

Comment: You're trying to run a string-manipulation function on an *object* and then wonder that there are problems ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills When I remove the ltrim I get no error. Also, when I remove the second preg_replace, no error as well.

Comment: @alfasin I thought I'd be dealing with strings when I ran simplexml_load_string($results) and then loop through each $result.

Comment: @AlxVallejo "Uncaught TypeError" sounds like a JavaScript error.  Is it PHP that's displaying that error?  I've never seen PHP use "object Object"

Comment: @AlxVallejo you should get the `data` (Strings) from the `XML` and only then preform string-manipulations. The fact that it runs is because PHP is loosely typed language - not because what you're doing is *right*...

Comment: @alfasin Are you telling me that my simplexml_load_string is being used incorrectly? I just tried running it in the loop instead of before and I get a bunch of NULL returned. As for manipulating strings, the strings were returned after running the first preg_replace...or is that an illusion...

Comment: @alfasin Getting the data from XML is executed as $result->label. Var_dumping that shows a string. I'm confused by your words... Actually, just kidding. It outputs an Object with numerical keys...